# List name column of Hyper-V VM using powershell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

This powershell command shows all Hyper-V VM which are running (with more columns: Name, State, CPU Usage, etc.):

```
Get-VM | where {$_.State -eq 'Running'}
```

How can I get list only with name column of all running Hyper-V VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that just select the property you need.

```
Get-VM | where {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | select Name
```

or VmName, not sure what's the proper property name